# Paginate based on the contained table on cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, pagination

Im developing a CMS with cakephp, i have 2 tables that i need to filter by some parameters, and for optimization i must do the query starting on the "hasMany" Model, the easy way will be make it on the "belongsTo" Model.

```
class Client extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    public $hasMany = array('Projects');
}

class Project extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    public $belongsTo = array('Client');
}
```

I have the where conditions in the $conditions array.

```
$this->paginate = array(
                'Client' => array(
                    'limit' => 20,
                    'conditions' => $conditions,
                    'contain' => array(
                        'Project' => array(
                            //'limit' => 20
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
$this->set('clients', $this->paginate('Client'));
```

By this way i get 20 Clients and all the projects inside each Client. If i uncomment the line i get 20 projects inside each of the 20 Clients.

I want 20 projects totally, doesnt matter how many clients (max 20).

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show the **projects**, you should paginate the **project**;

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'Project' => array(
        'limit' => 20,
            'conditions' => $conditions,

            // no need to set a limit on 'client',
            // as each project belongs to only one client
            'contain' => array(
                'Client'
            )
        )
);

$this->set('projects', $this->paginate('Project'));
```

It may be nescessary to add the `Project` model to your `$uses` array inside the controller